# Laravel live video Streaming over the server

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket

Hello I am new to socket programing in Laravel , I need to create a live streaming video in a project and I have tried  "https://packagist.org/packages/php-junior/laravel-video-chat" this package. After configuring the package, The response show that

**app.js:42617 GET https://video.dev505.io:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MsbESOE net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

over the time again and again.
I searched on google and no proper guidance available .
I tried this "https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/221" cure but all in vein ..

my Laravel-echo-server.json file

```
{
    "authHost": "https://127.0.0.1:6001",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "81110a9da500a734",
            "key": "b4f0effe8edc41963ba533939e37cba4"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "null",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/esportsecommerce.com/fullchain.pem",
    "sslKeyPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/esportsecommerce.com/privkey.pem",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": ""
}
```

my layout.app.blade.php file

```
    @yield('content')
</div>

<!-- Scripts {{ Request::getHost() }} -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<script src="//www.video.dev505.io:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I also started the server on Linux "Laravel-echo-server start" But repeatedly got the same response over and over again . Please is there anyone to guide properly in steps and solve the issue ? Also can someone atleast explain what are the proper steps to achieve realtime Laravel chat with video-streaming over the server ? Any small effort Will be much appreciated !

Comment: Can you check the  `sslCertPath` and the `sslKeyPath` again? Because for what I have done, I used `.crt` file for `sslCertPath` and `.key` file for `sslKeyPath`. But I am not sure if this is the issue, just an idea. Give it a try.

Comment: Hi, I was following the same tutorial and I got the same error. Can you tell me what you did to solve your problem?